# Choosing the simplest platform version of a source when porting to another platform

Tags: porting

The question will sound weird as I'm not very experienced in C, C++ and ASM.

Let's say I have a hard time finding a C# managed, safe-code-only solution to solve a problem. Then I find that in 1998, some codes for (e.g.) a codec have been written in C for PPC, x86, arm, etc. This code can have 20000+ lines, and I need to port it.

Then I try one platform, and notice a lot of API call, CUDA stuff, inline assembler in most of the code. Etc.

Is there a preference, concerning portability, between PPC, PS2, x86, arm, sparc, etc, when porting to another platform that helps reducing the number of platform-specific code occurrence? I know that all these builds exist especially because there are specific features on each processors, but I wonder if some processors have less antennas, third eye, and four legs, and are less simpler (or "limited") than others.

I spent the last week porting codes, and had the intuition that focusing on certain aspects helps finding more cross-platform code. I may be wrong, and I - know - that it highly depends on skill. But that doesn't change anything to the fact that, e.g., a 20000 lines Java code may be easier to port to .Net for Windows Phone than a x86 asm code.

More specifically, my question is about a good approach when porting Orange to Peach, and avoiding going through several platform specific implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you seem to be describing is that you have a highly-optimized C implementation of some codec that you need to bring to a platform-agnostic managed environment like .NET.

There are some problems with this.

A codec that has been optimized for several CPU architectures includes a lot of platform-specific code, because that's the only realistic way to achieve a level of performance that allows relatively real-time operation. This is why C and assembler were chosen over a managed language. (Setting aside the fact that it apparently predates most modern managed platforms - modern codecs like x264 and Vorbis are still written in C for this reason.) When performing complex transformations on large sets of data in a real-time setting, careful optimizations are made to account not merely for the CPU's features, but for the CPU's *behaviors.* The codec makes certain assumptions about the CPU's caches and timings to make the most of every single operation.

These kinds of optimizations are not possible in a managed environment. It is neither worth your time nor effort to port these kinds of things to a managed language.

Rather than porting this complex (and likely fragile!) code, you should instead use your chosen platform's ability to interact with *unmanaged* code. In .NET, you would probably want to use P/invoke to access the codec, and simply ship a pre-built copy of the codec for every platform you will deploy on.